# Видео внутри текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Нужно в **#30** вставить видео (Смотреть Картинку ниже по ссылку)
Чтобы в этой цифре с решеткой показывалось видео)))

Как можно реализовать такое?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW2Pa.png]

Comment: С такими задачами дорога прямо на переговоры с дизайнерами. И спросить именно у дизайнера, как он относится к поддержке экспериментальных технологий, и хочет ли он видеть их неработающими на большинстве устройств.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/QvvEYQ?q=text+mask&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=text+mask&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: Думаю в ваш вопрос стоит добавить ваши наработки, а вместо картинки можно и код добавить, будет куда лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать в After Effect без заднего слоя и просчитать в Alfa channel
Создаете слово, сверху кладете картинку. У слоя картинки ставите наложение по-моему ADD